# How to ensure only one cron entry with Ansible?

Tags: cron, ansible

I use the [`cron`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cron_module.html) module to add a crontab entry to managed hosts.

I realized that some of them already have this entry (it was probably added manually) and these systems now have two identical entries (and two jobs starting at the same time).

**Is there a way to ensure that only one entry matching requirements (timing and command) is present?**

I had a similar problem with `lineinfile` and ended up first deleting all matching lines, then recreate a single one (in the meantime I found [a post](https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-use-ansibles-lineinfile-module-in-a-bulletproof-way) explaining the exact same approach). This works for files, though, and not for crontabs (which are ultimately files but I doubt I can safely edit them directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a generic Linux machine, you should be able to place a file in /etc/cron.d/. It uses root-style crontab, so you specify a user as the sixth item, and the command as the seventh.

You should place one "entry" per file- so you might have /etc/cron.d/cleanup, /etc/cron.d/makeasandwich, and so on. You can use `copy` or `template` to generate them.

There's also a [`cron` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cron_module.html), but it has some of the massive problems that `lineinfile` has. It's much better to be confident about what your server configuration is.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, much more manageable than directly crontab, thanks !